# Get error after install nativescript-plugin-firebase when build for android using nativescript sidekick

Tags: android, nativescript, nativescript-plugin, sidekick

I installed nativescript-plugin-firebase step by step according to the document, but every time when I use sidekick on MacOS to build or run the app for android. I always get the error, the log is below:

```
 [18-11-08 09:36:09.139] NativeScript Sidekick version: 1.13.0-v.2018.10.5.2
[18-11-08 09:36:09.492] Checking for updates...
[18-11-08 09:36:09.795] Dependencies versions: NodeJS: 10.13.0, npm: 6.4.1, NativeScript CLI: 4.2.4.
[18-11-08 09:36:10.769] No updates available.
[18-11-08 09:36:11.214] (CLI) Using NativeScript CLI located in /Users/huizhang/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/lib/node_modules/nativescript
[18-11-08 09:36:11.520] (CLI) Searching for devices...
[18-11-08 09:36:11.643] Loaded CLI extension nativescript-cloud, version 1.14.2.
[18-11-08 09:36:11.644] Loaded CLI extension nativescript-starter-kits, version 0.3.5.
[18-11-08 09:36:18.878] Devices service initialized.
[18-11-08 09:36:20.538] The user hui zhang logged in.
[18-11-08 09:37:29.601] App with path: /project/testmyapp was opened.
[18-11-08 09:37:39.846] Build started.
[18-11-08 09:37:45.403] (CLI) Executing before-liveSync hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/before-liveSync/nativescript-angular-sync.js
[18-11-08 09:37:45.420] (CLI) Executing before-watchPatterns hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/before-watchPatterns/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
[18-11-08 09:37:45.423] (CLI) Executing before-watchPatterns hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/before-watchPatterns/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
[18-11-08 09:37:45.464] (CLI) Executing before-watch hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/before-watch/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
[18-11-08 09:37:45.474] (CLI) Found peer TypeScript 2.7.2
[18-11-08 09:37:47.854] (CLI) Executing before-watch hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/before-watch/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
[18-11-08 09:37:47.896] (CLI) Copying template files...
[18-11-08 09:37:49.233] (CLI) Platform android successfully added. v5.0.0
[18-11-08 09:37:49.235] (CLI) Executing before-checkForChanges hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/before-checkForChanges/firebase-copy-google-services.js
[18-11-08 09:37:49.243] (CLI) nativescript-plugin-firebase: /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/.pluginfirebaseinfo not found, forcing prepare!
[18-11-08 09:37:49.264] (CLI) Executing before-shouldPrepare hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/before-shouldPrepare/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
[18-11-08 09:37:49.269] (CLI) Executing before-prepare hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
[18-11-08 09:37:49.271] (CLI) Hook skipped because either bundling or livesync is in progress.
[18-11-08 09:37:49.271] (CLI) Executing before-prepare hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/before-prepare/nativescript-plugin-firebase.js
[18-11-08 09:37:49.274] (CLI) Preparing project...
[18-11-08 09:37:49.275] (CLI) Executing before-prepareJSApp hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/before-prepareJSApp/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
[18-11-08 09:37:53.811] (CLI) Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-angular for android.
[18-11-08 09:37:53.989] (CLI) Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-plugin-firebase for android.
[18-11-08 09:37:54.177] (CLI) Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-theme-core for android.
[18-11-08 09:37:54.412] (CLI) Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules for android.
[18-11-08 09:37:54.645] (CLI) Successfully prepared plugin nativescript-intl for android.
[18-11-08 09:37:54.857] (CLI) Successfully prepared plugin tns-core-modules-widgets for android.
[18-11-08 09:37:58.056] (CLI) Project successfully prepared (Android)
[18-11-08 09:37:58.057] (CLI) Executing after-prepare hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/after-prepare/firebase-build-gradle.js
[18-11-08 09:37:58.062] (CLI) Configure firebase
[18-11-08 09:37:58.064] (CLI) Executing after-prepare hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/after-prepare/firebase-copy-google-services.js
[18-11-08 09:37:58.070] (CLI) Copy /project/testmyapp/App_Resources/Android/google-services.json to /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/google-services.json.
[18-11-08 09:37:58.071] (CLI) Executing after-prepare hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/after-prepare/firebase-crashlytics-buildscript.js
[18-11-08 09:37:58.152] (CLI) Executing after-prepare hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/after-prepare/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
[18-11-08 09:37:58.406] (CLI) Executing after-prepare hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/after-prepare/nativescript-plugin-firebase.js
[18-11-08 09:37:58.416] (CLI) Executing before-checkForChanges hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/before-checkForChanges/firebase-copy-google-services.js
[18-11-08 09:37:58.419] (CLI) nativescript-plugin-firebase: building for same environment, not forcing prepare.
[18-11-08 09:37:59.080] (CLI) Executing before-shouldPrepare hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/before-shouldPrepare/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
[18-11-08 09:37:59.081] (CLI) Skipping prepare.
[18-11-08 09:37:59.081] (CLI) Building project...
[18-11-08 09:37:59.088] (CLI) Gradle build...
[18-11-08 09:38:06.241] (CLI) + setting applicationId
[18-11-08 09:38:06.652] (CLI) + applying user-defined configuration from /project/testmyapp/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle
[18-11-08 09:38:06.739] (CLI) Applying settings from /project/testmyapp/App_Resources/Android/settings.json
[18-11-08 09:38:06.839] (CLI) Using support library version 25.3.1
[18-11-08 09:38:06.843] (CLI) + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: nativescript-optimized-with-inspector
[18-11-08 09:38:06.939] (CLI) + adding aar plugin dependency: /project/testmyapp/node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/android/firebase-release.aar
[18-11-08 09:38:06.942] (CLI) + adding aar plugin dependency: /project/testmyapp/node_modules/tns-core-modules-widgets/platforms/android/widgets-release.aar
[18-11-08 09:38:08.760] (CLI) registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
[18-11-08 09:38:08.940] (CLI) registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
[18-11-08 09:39:45.942] (CLI) FAILURE:
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI) Build failed with an exception.
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI) * What went wrong:
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI) Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI) > Android resource linking failed
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)   Output:  /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v26/values-v26.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)   /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v26/values-v26.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)   /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v26/values-v26.xml:15: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)   /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:365: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)   /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:365: error: resource android:attr/font not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)   /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:365: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)   error: failed linking references.
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)   Command: /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar/85ea540e67605d295c7a7069376ea600/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           /usr/local/share/android-sdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           --manifest\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           -o\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           -R\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           @/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           --auto-add-overlay\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           --java\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           --custom-package\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           org.nativescript.testmyapp\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           -0\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           apk\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           --no-version-vectors\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           --output-text-symbols\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)           --no-version-vectors
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx Daemon #0
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)   Output:  /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar/383dd78d0308c0cefdfb66151ed40710/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)   /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar/383dd78d0308c0cefdfb66151ed40710/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)   /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar/383dd78d0308c0cefdfb66151ed40710/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:17:5-93: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)   /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/design-25.3.1.aar/b8b80cbef697cdfa8c7781688061fe84/res/values/values.xml:161:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)   /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/design-25.3.1.aar/b8b80cbef697cdfa8c7781688061fe84/res/values/values.xml:161:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)   /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/design-25.3.1.aar/b8b80cbef697cdfa8c7781688061fe84/res/values/values.xml:161:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:45.945] (CLI)   error: failed linking references.
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI) Command: /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar/85ea540e67605d295c7a7069376ea600/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           /usr/local/share/android-sdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           --manifest\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           -o\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           -R\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           @/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           --auto-add-overlay\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           --java\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           --custom-package\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           org.nativescript.testmyapp\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           -0\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           apk\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           --no-version-vectors\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           --output-text-symbols\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)           --no-version-vectors
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI)   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx Daemon #0
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI) * Try:
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI) Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI) * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[18-11-08 09:39:45.949] (CLI) BUILD FAILED in 1m 46s
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI) Unable to apply changes on device: a44ddccb. Error is: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1 Error output:
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI) FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI) * What went wrong:
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI) Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI) > Android resource linking failed
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   Output:  /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v26/values-v26.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v26/values-v26.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v26/values-v26.xml:15: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:365: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:365: error: resource android:attr/font not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:365: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   error: failed linking references.
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   Command: /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar/85ea540e67605d295c7a7069376ea600/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           /usr/local/share/android-sdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           --manifest\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           -o\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           -R\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           @/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           --auto-add-overlay\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           --java\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           --custom-package\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           org.nativescript.testmyapp\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           -0\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           apk\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           --no-version-vectors\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           --output-text-symbols\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           --no-version-vectors
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx Daemon #0
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   Output:  /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar/383dd78d0308c0cefdfb66151ed40710/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar/383dd78d0308c0cefdfb66151ed40710/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar/383dd78d0308c0cefdfb66151ed40710/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:17:5-93: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/design-25.3.1.aar/b8b80cbef697cdfa8c7781688061fe84/res/values/values.xml:161:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/design-25.3.1.aar/b8b80cbef697cdfa8c7781688061fe84/res/values/values.xml:161:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/design-25.3.1.aar/b8b80cbef697cdfa8c7781688061fe84/res/values/values.xml:161:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   error: failed linking references.
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   Command: /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar/85ea540e67605d295c7a7069376ea600/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           /usr/local/share/android-sdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           --manifest\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           -o\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           -R\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           @/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           --auto-add-overlay\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           --java\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           --custom-package\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           org.nativescript.testmyapp\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           -0\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           apk\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           --no-version-vectors\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           --output-text-symbols\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)           --no-version-vectors
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI)   Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx Daemon #0
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI) * Try:
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI) Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI) * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[18-11-08 09:39:46.394] (CLI) BUILD FAILED in 1m 46s
[18-11-08 09:39:46.399] (CLI) Executing after-watch hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
[18-11-08 09:39:46.402] (CLI) Stopping tsc watch
[18-11-08 09:39:46.402] (CLI) Executing after-watch hook from /project/testmyapp/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
[18-11-08 09:39:46.402] (CLI) Stopping webpack watch
[18-11-08 09:39:46.406] Error detected during LiveSync on a44ddccb for /project/testmyapp. Error: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
Output:  /project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v26/values-v26.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v26/values-v26.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values-v26/values-v26.xml:15: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:365: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:365: error: resource android:attr/font not found.
/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:365: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
error: failed linking references.
Command: /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar/85ea540e67605d295c7a7069376ea600/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar\
--manifest\
/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
-o\
/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
-R\
@/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
--auto-add-overlay\
--java\
/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
--custom-package\
org.nativescript.testmyapp\
-0\
apk\
--no-version-vectors\
--output-text-symbols\
/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
--no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx Daemon #0
Output:  /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar/383dd78d0308c0cefdfb66151ed40710/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
/Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar/383dd78d0308c0cefdfb66151ed40710/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
/Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.0.2.aar/383dd78d0308c0cefdfb66151ed40710/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:17:5-93: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
/Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/design-25.3.1.aar/b8b80cbef697cdfa8c7781688061fe84/res/values/values.xml:161:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
/Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/design-25.3.1.aar/b8b80cbef697cdfa8c7781688061fe84/res/values/values.xml:161:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font not found.
/Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/design-25.3.1.aar/b8b80cbef697cdfa8c7781688061fe84/res/values/values.xml:161:5-202: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
error: failed linking references.
Command: /Users/huizhang/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx.jar/85ea540e67605d295c7a7069376ea600/aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
/usr/local/share/android-sdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar\
--manifest\
/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/processDebugManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
-o\
/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/processed_res/debug/processDebugResources/out/resources-debug.ap_\
-R\
@/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugResources/resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
--auto-add-overlay\
--java\
/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debug/processDebugResources/r\
--custom-package\
org.nativescript.testmyapp\
-0\
apk\
--no-version-vectors\
--output-text-symbols\
/project/testmyapp/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/symbols/debug/R.txt\
--no-version-vectors
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-osx Daemon #0
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 1m 46s
[18-11-08 09:39:46.418] Stopped LiveSync on a44ddccb for /project/testmyapp.
```

The same code can be built successfully for ios when using sidekick and emulator on macos but can not run correctly only show the nativescript logo then exist. Can anybody help me to solve this problem? I spent a long time try to fix this but get no clue. Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw5iT.png)

Comment: Are you using {N} v5?

Comment: No I use 4.2.4 version

Comment: If you are using runtime & core modules 4.2.4 then you must use CLI 4.2.x, by any chance have you upgraded your CLI to 5.x?

Answer (score 0):

In log there is a piece:

```
[18-11-08 09:37:49.233] (CLI) Platform android successfully added. v5.0.0
```

You said in comments, you are using version 4.2.4.
Try downgrading your platform version.

Comment: Hi, in my terminal when I run tns --version it shows the version is 4.2.4. Can you tell me more about how to downgrade my platform version? Thanks. The screen shot link is https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw5iT.png

Comment: first off, check your ```package.json```. There's line ```tns-android``` with it's version. If it's ```5.0.0```, change it to ```4.2.0```. Next, remove ```platforms``` directory. Then run ```tns platform add```, and it should result with: ```Platform android successfully added. v4.2.0```.

In file it looks like this (look at android section. ignore iOS, i'm just using 5.0.0):
https://imgur.com/a/Fjnod55

Comment: still build failed

Comment: Have you solved it yet? Does `tns doctor` result with any kind of error?